# Communication between Java programs with non-JDK objects

Tags: java, rmi, xml-rpc, rpc, xmlrpcclient

I'm looking for a communication channel between two java programs running on the same machine. I've found a few options (RMI and XML-RCP) but none of the examples that I found show exchange of objects wich class it's non-primitive and not know on JDK (our own objects).

So, what's the easy technology to use when I want to do this (note that Utils.jar it's on the classpath of Server.jar and Client.jar):

Utils.jar:

```
class MyClassRequestParams { ... }

class MyClassReturnParams { ... }
```

Client.jar:

```
// Server creation
...

// Send request
MyClassRequestParams params = new MyClass...

MyClassReturnParams response = server.send("serverMethodName", params);
```

Server.jar:

```
MyClassRequestParams serverMethodName(MyClassRequestParams params)
{
   MyClassReturnParams response = new MyC...

   // do processing

   return response;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make your transport classes implement the Serializable interface, and everything will be fine with RMI. Note that every object referenced bt the transport object should also be Serializable.

The [RMI tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/overview.html) uses an example with a custom Task interface implemented by a Pi custom class that is not a "standard" JDK class.

Answer (score 1):

You may also consider [Versile Java](https://versile.com/products/vjava/) (I am one of its developers). Follow the link for an example of making remote calls and defining remote interfaces. It implements a platform-independent standard for remote ORB interaction, currently also available for python.